# Unable to Create New session with Microsoft Edge with desired capabilities

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, microsoft-edge, selenium-edgedriver

I am trying to create a Java test using Edge Webdriver and Edge version 86 (available to download).

I am using EdgeOptions as suggested on many threads here

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.edge.driver", "C:\\edgedriver\\msedgedriver.exe"); 
EdgeOptions edgeOptions = new EdgeOptions();
WebDriver driver = new EdgeDriver(edgeOptions); 
driver.get("https://bing.com");
```

I get the below error when i execute the script

***Error:***

Starting MSEdgeDriver 86.0.622.43 (aecc56815110f44c6552813fdd27a416872192c8) on port 35032
Only local connections are allowed.

Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping MSEdgeDriver safe.

MSEdgeDriver was started successfully.

org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create new remote session. desired capabilities = Capabilities [{browserName=MicrosoftEdge, version=, platform=WINDOWS}], required capabilities = Capabilities [{}]

Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: '5234b32', time: '2017-03-10 09:00:17 -0800'

System info: host: 'XXXXXXXXXX', ip: 'XXXXXXX', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_191'

Driver info: driver.version: EdgeDriver

Comment: Have you tried doing what that link suggests?

Comment: We are not allowed to use Chromedriver due to vulnerability concerns. We are trying to get Edeg driver working

Comment: You are starting the `MSEdgeDriver`. However, Edge is now on Chromium too.

Comment: Does that mean Chrome Desiredcapabilities will work for Edge ?

Comment: I suggest you try to remove the `edgeOptions` from your code and then try to run the code. see whether it works or not. Because you had created the object for the `edgeOptions` but you are not setting any option or capability using it.